# pdf from web service to iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can a file be downloaded from a server?

Is there any way for sending pdf file from a web service to an *iPhone*?

Is it necessary to convert the pdf to any other form and then send it also reconvert it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily download your pdf file using below code

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadUrl]];

    //Store the Data locally as PDF File

NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
NSString *pdf1;
pdf1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",yourBookTitle];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdf1];

[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

for your second question store your pdf file in to server and get the Url no need to convert in any format